# SQL query to compute calculations from different rows of the same table in SQL server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I want a SQL query for the following. I am a novice in SQL. And below table is just an example of the kind of data I have. I have very big data of about 30 million rows and would like to write a query to get the below output table.

```
   Id        type        data          time
-----------------------------------------------------------
    1          30          3.9          15:50:10.660555
    1          30          4.0          15:50:10.660777
    1          70          11.5         15:50:10.797966
    1          30          4.1          15:50:10.834444
    1          70          12.6         15:50:10.853114
    1          70          16.7         15:50:10.955086
    1          30          5            15:50:10.99
    11         30          3.8          15:50:11.660555
    11         30          4.1          15:50:11.660777
    11         70          12.5         15:50:11.797966
    11         30          4.7          15:50:11.834444
    11         70          12.68        15:50:11.853114
    11         70          16.76        15:50:11.955086
    11         30          5.1          15:50:11.99
```

I have a table like the above. For each type 70, I need to calculate something with the last known type 30. For instance, for Id = 1, for the first type = 70 data at 15:50:10.797966, I need to get type = 30 data at 15:50:10.660777 so that I can calculate result = 11.5/4.0. Similarly, for type = 70 at 15:50:10.853114, I want data of type = 30 at 15:50:10.834444, so my result = 12.6/4.1.

I want the output to look like this:

```
Id          type           result             time
------------------------------------------------------
1            70             11.5/4.0        15:50:10.797966
1            70             12.6/4.1        15:50:10.853114
1            70             16.7/4.1        15:50:10.955086
11           70             12.5/4.1        15:50:11.797966
11           70             12.68/4.7       15:50:11.853114
11           70             16.76/4.7       15:50:11.955086
```

I would like to be able to execute these SQL queries in python using pyodbc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You have tagged both mysql and postgresql, which are you actually using? They have different features so the answer might be different depending which database is used. Also please specify what version of the database you are using.

Comment: @harmic: I apologize, actually it's SQL server 2017.

Comment: do you have no `date` component in `time`?

Comment: @vkp: I do have date component, but it's not needed because each file id has the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is atleast one type=30 row preceding type=70 per id, you can do this using `outer apply`, getting the `max` time for type=30 before each type=70 row and using that value for division.

```
SELECT x.id,
       x.type,
       x.time,
       x.data*1.0/t.data as result
FROM
  (SELECT t.*,t1.maxtime_before
   FROM t 
   OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT max(time) AS maxtime_before
      FROM t t1
      WHERE t1.id=t.id AND t1.type=30 AND t1.time<t.time) t1
   WHERE type = 70
  ) x
JOIN t ON t.id=x.id AND t.time=x.maxtime_before
```

If there is no row with type=30 preceding a type=70 row, you can show a `null` value for that time in the result column using

```
WITH x AS
  (SELECT t.*,
          t1.maxtime_before
   FROM t
   OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT max(time) AS maxtime_before
      FROM t t1
      WHERE t1.id=t.id AND t1.type=30 AND t1.time<t.time) t1
   WHERE type = 70
  )
SELECT x.id,
       x.type,
       x.time,
       x.data*1.0/t.data as resullt
FROM t
JOIN x ON t.id=x.id AND t.time=x.maxtime_before
UNION ALL
SELECT id,
       type,
       time,
       NULL
FROM x
WHERE maxtime_before IS NULL
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/KZIP74756)

One more way to do it is using `max` window function to keep track of the running max time of type=30 row per id.

```
WITH x AS
  (SELECT t.*,
          MAX(CASE WHEN type=30 THEN time END) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) AS running_max
   FROM t
  )
SELECT x.id,
       x.type,
       x.time,
       x.data*1.0/t.data as result
FROM x
JOIN t ON t.id=x.id AND t.time=x.running_max
WHERE x.type=70
UNION ALL
SELECT id,
       type,
       time,
       NULL
FROM x 
WHERE running_max IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way you can do this with only window functions.

For each row, get the previous type and value.  Also, enumerate the 70s in such a way that you can identify them as a group (you can do this with a cumulative sum).

In the next step, use a partitioned max to get the type and finally do your calculation.

```
select t.*,
       data / data_30 as result
from (select t.*,
             max(case when prev_type = 30 then prev_data end) over (partition by id, grp) as data_30
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when type <> 70 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by time) as grp,
                   lag(type) over (partition by id order by time) as prev_type,
                   lag(data) over (partition by id order by time) as prev_data
            from t
            where type in (30, 70)
           ) t
     ) t;
```

One interesting aspect of this.  By limiting the types only to 30 and 70, we guarantee that each group of 70s is directly preceded by a 30.

Comment: @Gingerbread . . . This should be much more efficient than the answer using `cross apply`.